# Is a random variable squared different from being multiplied by itself

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm trying to understand how random variable work. As I understand a random variable squared will square all the outcomes of a random variable. But if you multiplied a random variable X by itself you would get a random variable that takes two random outcomes from X and multiplies them together. So then the probability functions of X squared and X multiplied by itself would be different.

Is this the correct way to think about this case?

Comment: A random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ that assigns to each outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ a real number $X(\omega)$. The map $x\to x^2$ is measurable, and hence $X^2$ is also a random variable, which assigns to each outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ the real number $X(\omega)^2$. That is how you should think of these things; the "outcomes" are not what are being multiplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are mentioning first is correct. So we draw from distribution of $X$ and squared it and make a distribution out of this.

What you are mentioning next is quite unclear and might lead to misunderstanding, but I will explain how I interpreted it.

So first I don't think saying multiplying random variable $X$ by itself is a good way of putting it. A better way of describing it is we have two random variable e.g. $X_1$ and $X_2$ both of which are identically distributed and then we have $Y=X_1 X_2$. Bear in mind I haven't mentioned independence, since independence between those two will change how $Y$ is distributed.